# Why 'null' or 'undefined' "is assignable" to parameter of type 'string'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's have [the following code in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQHwAoCGAuRNAGkQCMC0BKRAb0QF8AoR4LAIhzZIEZKBuIA):

```
function f<T>(a: T, b: T) { }

f("a", 1);
```

TypeScript expectedly fails with:

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

However, [when I pass `null` (or `undefined`) instead of `1`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQHwAoCGAuRNAGkQCMC0BKRAb0QF8AoR4LAIhzZLBABtfKAbiA), TypeScript changes the type of generic parameter `<T>` to `string | null` and does not fail.

I have two questions:

- Why `null` or `undefined` is treated differently than e.g. `number`?
- And how to prevent the widening (changing type to `string | null`)?

Comment: TypeScript is inferring the union type `string | null` because both `a` and `b` are equally applicable inference sites for `T`. If the type of `a` should depend on the type of `b`, then you can write `function f<T, U extends T>(a: T, b: U) { }`. I realize that's not your question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why null or undefined is treated differently than e.g. number?

To be honest I am not 100% sure why. As mentioned in the comments it's inferring that `a` is of type 'string' but allows `null | undefined. I did some experimenting and I could not figure out why it's doing this.

> And how to prevent the widening (changing type to string | null)?
> Some examples of what you can do:

```js
// Original
function f<T>(a: T, b: T) { }

f('a', 'b')  // Allowed
f(1, 2) // Allowed
f(true, false) // Allowed
f("a", 1); // Has error
f("a", undefined); // Allowed
f("a", null); // Allowed
f(null, null) // Allowed

// Extending then defining
// Will only allow strings
function g<T extends string = string>(a: T, b: T) { }

g('a', 'b')  // Allowed
g(1, 2) // Has error
g(true, false) // Has error
g("a", 1); // Has error
g("a", undefined); // Has error
g("a", null); // Has error
g(null, null) // Has error

// Using Required
// Does not allow null or undefined but allows other non strings
function x<T>(a: Required<T>, b: Required<T>) { }

x('a', 'b') // Allowed
x(1, 2) // Allowed
x(true, false) // Allowed
x("a", 1); // Has error
x("a", undefined); // Has error
x("a", null); // Has error
x(null, null) // Has error
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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